# reinit jquery after iframe postbacks using innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

hia

i am trying some jquery stuff.  simple, basically:  it's a page with a table.  i have a simpe jquery that creates a effect on the tr's for onmouseover/out and a toggle when clicking on a line.  clicking on a line ALSO fires a http-request into an iframe which generates two new tables and writes them back to the parent window using innerHTML javascript.

that new tables, created from within the iframe use the same jquery stuff for the onmouseover/out effect.  but this does not work because i assume the $(document).ready(function() is way past running and did not 'process' that newly inserted tables.

how can i rerun $(document).ready(function() from within the iframe?  simply writing a javascript back to the parent did not work, as it is not being executed (also test with a simple 'alert').  i already put all jquery init stuff into a separate function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initjquery()
});

function initjquery(){
        $("#jqtbody tr").bind( "mouseover", function(e){
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
        });
        $("#jqtbody tr").bind( "mouseout", function(e){
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
        });
    }
```

see the image for some visual 'help' (sorry, i'm new, i am not allowed to inlay images here yet)
http://beta2.nextron.ch/temp/unibas.jpg

thanks for any help!

lukas

Comment: Have you tried the `live` method of jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

- 1) create  placeholders to hold the dynamic tables, when they are requested
- 2) when you fire the http request, be sure to return ONLY the full html of the table ( no need of iframes)
- 3) when the request arrives to the page ( html source of the table ), place this table into the  placeholder with $(placeholder).append ( htmlOfTheDynamicTable )

By using this approach, and by using the append(), jQuery automatically loads all the events for that elements as well. If you go by direct innerHTML ( or, in jQuery style, with a $(target).html( html ) ), the events that "should" be attached to the dynamically-loaded HTML won't work.